# Not importing CSS into React component Library bundling with Rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, rollup

I am creating a react component library with Typescript, rollup is used as bundler. My rollup config is:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";

// To handle css files
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';


const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
      
      terser(),
      image()
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],

    external: [/\.css$/], // telling rollup anything that is .css aren't part of type exports 
  },
]
```

Following is the code for Alert.tsx (react component):

```
import cn from 'clsx'
import s from './Alert.module.css'
import React from 'react'
export interface AlertProps {
  message: string
  size?: 'small' | 'normal'
  type: 'error' | 'success' | 'info'
}

/*** This is a Alert Component */ 
const Alert: React.FC<AlertProps> = (props) => {
  const { type, size } = props
  const rootClassName = cn(s.root, {
    [s.error]: type === 'error',
    [s.small]: size === 'small',
    [s.normal]: !size || size === 'normal',
    [s.info]: type === 'info',
  })

  return <div className={rootClassName}>{props.message}</div>
}

export default Alert
```

I am using this library with my other react project. Below is the code for App.js:

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";

import { Button, Alert, Logo, } from "pw-omni-ui";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React component</h1>
      <Alert message="This is a alert box" size="small" type="error" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As Alert type is set to error, there is no css applied when the alert component is rendered. Therefore the problem is CSS is not shipped when the react component library is bundled